# No encuentro solución a la ejecución de éste evento

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, formularios, eventos

Estoy trabajando sobre una web que no diseñé/programé yo. Ya tiene *bootstrap* y *jQuery*. La tarea era realizar una ventana modal sobre un formulario.

Al hacer clic en `Enviar` deberá de ejecutar esa ventana modal (para ésto utilice el *bootstrap*) y el envío final del formulario lo deberá de ejecutar la ventana modal, que realiza una pregunta

HTML:

```
<form id="contact" action="contacto.php" method="post">
        <!-- Campo engaño para spam-->
        <input type="text" name="e-mail" value="" style="height: 0px; opacity: 0" />

        <fieldset>
            <input name="nombre" placeholder="Su nombre" type="text" tabindex="1" required autofocus />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <input name="email" placeholder="Su email" type="email" tabindex="2" required />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <input name="tel" placeholder="Teléfono de contacto" type="tel" tabindex="3" required />
            <input name="es" id="es" type="hidden" tabindex="3" value="no" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <textarea name="mensaje" placeholder="Escriba su mensaje" tabindex="5" required></textarea>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <button type="submit" name="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-envio" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Enviar">
                Enviar
            </button>
        </fieldset>
```

Y éste es el js:

```
$("#contact").submit(function(evform) {
        evform.preventDefault();
    })

    $("#esDeudor").click(
        function() {
            $("#es").val("deudor");
            $("#contact").submit();
        }
    )
```

En éste caso solo tomo el botón **"deudor"** y no el otro, que sería igual solo que con diferente **ID**.

Y sucede que el **submit()** no se ejecuta. El *submit* lo que debe hacer es cargar una **pagina PHP** que manda los datos por email.

Answer (score 1):

No se puede enviar el formulario porque lo estás cancelando y puedes comprobarlo con este fragmento de código.

```js
$('#mi-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    console.log('Cancelando envío');
    // Debes eliminar esta línea
    e.preventDefault();
});

// Asignar evento al botón para poder evitar que se envíe el formulario
$('#btn-enviar').on('click', e => {
    console.log('Cancelando acción de botón Enviar');
    // Cancelar envío
    e.preventDefault();
    // Aquí debes mostrar la ventana modal
});

// El botón de la ventana modal sí debe poder enviar
$('#btn-ok').on('click', e => {
    console.log('Enviar formulario');
    $('#mi-form').submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="mi-form">
    <input type="text" name="nombre">
    <button type="submit" id="btn-enviar">Enviar</button>
</form>

<button id="btn-ok">Sí, enviar</button>
```

Lo que debes hacer es cancelar el evento del botón Enviar, ahí muestras la ventana modal y en el método `submit()` del formulario eliminas la línea `evform.preventDefault();`